# How can I have form validation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form that checks for JavaScript validation before it goes into my database basically if a user does not type in anything  then a alert will come up, however when viewing it in the browser, when I don't place any text inside any of the text boxes and hit submit, no alert comes up,  no nothing i'd appreciate it if you could help me out please

## HTML

```
<body>
<form action="update.php?eventID=<?=$contact['eventID']?>" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validate()" method="post">

    <label for="eventTitle">Event Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventTitle" value="?=$contact['eventTitle']?>" id="eventTitle">

    <label for="eventDescription">Event Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventDescription" value="<?=$contact['eventDescription']?>" id="eventDescription">

    <label for="eventStartDate">Event Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventStartDate" value="<?=$contact['eventStartDate']?>" id="eventStartDate">

    <label for="eventEndDate">Event End Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventEndDate" value="<?=$contact['eventEndDate']?>" id="eventEndDate">

    <label for="eventPrice">Event Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventPrice" value="<?=$contact['eventPrice']?>" id="eventPrice">

    <input type="submit" value="Update">

</form> 

<script src="update.js"></script>
</body>
```

## JavaScript

```
function validate() {
     if( document.myForm.eventTitle.value == "" ) {
           alert( "Please enter a Event Title" );
            document.myForm.eventTitle.focus() ;
            return false; 
         }

         if( document.myForm.eventDescription.value == "" ) {
            alert( "Please enter a event Description!" );
            document.myForm.eventDescription.focus() ;
            return false;
         }
          if( document.myForm.eventStartDate.value == "" ) {
            alert( "Please enter a event Start Date!" );
            document.myForm.eventStartDate.focus() ;
             return false;
        }
          if( document.myForm.eventEndDate.value == "" ) {
            alert( "Please enter a event End Date!" );
            document.myForm.eventEndDate.focus() ;
            return false;
        }

         if( document.myForm.eventPrice.value == "" ) {
            alert( "Please enter a event End Date!" );
            document.myForm.eventPrice.focus() ;
           return false;

         }
          return( true );
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given value for each input e.g. `value="?=$contact['eventTitle']?>"`

If you remove that you will get an alert.

Answer (score 1):

The only error I found in your code is a missing minor sign before question mark in the line where you define eventTitle
Fix the typo, try clearing browser cache, and try pressing F12 to access debug information to better understand what's going wrong.